# Amo-YouTube and Transition mode

Tags: youtube, amp-youtube

I am running a Wordpress (neve theme + Beaver build) site in transition mode of AMP plugin. I have some YouTube videos embedded on the regular way and I would like to start using the amp-YouTube to show this embedded videos.

Problem is: the YouTube videos embedded the regular way show up on both AMP and non-AMP views of the site.
The YouTube videos embedded with amp-youtube shows only on AMP-view.

Is there a workaround to show the videos embedded with amp-youtube on both AMP and non-AMP views? I need the same video to show up on both AMP and non-AMP views...

(Note: I am far from being a hard site developer!)

Answer (score 0):

Does the same occur with the default WordPress editor using the YouTube block? Why not ask in the AMP plugins support forums?